# Javascript: Why the scrollHeight value is different in Chrome and Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

I have below codes:

```
const HIDDEN_STYLE = `
  height:0 !important;
  visibility:hidden !important;
  overflow:hidden !important;
  position:absolute !important;
  z-index:-1000 !important;
  top:0 !important;
  right:0 !important
`;

const contextStr = "letter-spacing:normal;line-height:20px;padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:14px;font-weight:400;font-size:14px;text-rendering:optimizelegibility;text-transform:none;width:501.683px;text-indent:0px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:60px;border-width:;box-sizing:border-box"

const hiddenTextarea = document.createElement('textarea')
document.body.appendChild(hiddenTextarea)
hiddenTextarea.setAttribute('style', `${contextStr};${HIDDEN_STYLE}`);

console.log('scroll height : ', hiddenTextarea.scrollHeight)
```

My Firefox version: 87.0

My Chrome version: 90.0.4430.72

The `scrollHeight` value output in Firefox browser is **34**, but in Chrome browser the value is **48**. I don't know why Firefox get 34 here, can anyone explain it ?

Comment: It's because of your `padding`. Setting it to `padding: 0;` will result in **20** on both browsers

Comment: @Reyno Can I know the detailed reason ? Why with padding here will make the scroll height to 34 ?